# Como validar um nome civil brasileiro?

Tags: validação, português-do-brasil

Como validar nomes de pessoas, em português do Brasil?

Comment: No Brasil ainda deve-se preocupar com os nomes indígenas - Validação de nome sempre vai ser algo de bastante discussão e preocupação para nós programadores, eu mesmo parei de esquentar a cabeça com isto a algum tempo rsrsrs

Answer (score 24):

O alfabeto português é baseado no [alfabeto latino](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_latino#Alfabeto_B.C3.A1sico), que consiste de 26 caracteres:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Somado a estes caracteres, o alfabeto português (do Brasil) acrescenta os seguintes [símbolos diacríticos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_portugu%C3%AAs#Acentos_gr.C3.A1ficos_e_sinais_diacr.C3.ADticos):

> - [`~` (Til)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Til): nasaliza a vogal "a" e os ditongos "ae", "oe" e "ao" -- ã / ãe / õe / ão.
> - [`¸` (Cedilha)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilha): confere à letra "c" o som da letra "s" diante de "a", "o" e "u" -- ç.
> - [`^` (Acento Circunflexo)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_circunflexo): indica a sílaba tónica e fecha o timbre das vogais "a", "e" e "o", nos casos em que se requer acentuação gráfica -- â / ê / ô.
> - [`´` (Acento Agudo)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_agudo): indica a sílaba tónica e abre o timbre das vogais nos casos em que se requer acentuação gráfica -- á / é / í / ó / ú.
> - [`` ` `` (Acento Grave)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_grave): utilizado para marcar o caso dativo feminino (à), por oposição a "ao" (masculino), e dos pronomes "aquele", "aquela" e "aquilo" - à.
> - [`¨` (Trema)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema): atualmente utilizado somente no português brasileiro para indicar o pronunciamento da vogal "u" nas seqüências "qüe", "qüi", "güe" e "güi" - ü.

Então, além da tradicional faixa `a-z` e `A-Z`, temos que incluir também os caracteres `ãõ`, `ç`, `âêô` `à`, `áéíóú` e `ü`. E claro, não podemos esquecer do espaço em branco.

O regex ficaria:

```
[^a-zA-ZáéíóúàâêôãõüçÁÉÍÓÚÀÂÊÔÃÕÜÇ ]
```

Lembre-se ainda de:

- Tratar eventuais espaços em branco no ínicio e no final do nome ([trim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28programming%29)).
- Verificar a existência de espaços em branco consecutivos.

---

## Exemplo (C#)

```cs
public static string TratarNome(string nome)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nome)) throw new ArgumentException("Um nome em branco foi passado.");

    // Removendo caracteres em branco no ínicio e no final do nome:
    nome = nome.Trim();

    // Trocando dois ou mais espaços em branco consecutivos por apenas um:
    nome = Regex.Replace(nome, "[ ]{2,}", " ", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    // Verificando a ocorrência de caracteres inválidos no alfabeto português (do Brasil):
    if (Regex.IsMatch(nome, "[^a-zA-ZáéíóúàâêôãõüçÁÉÍÓÚÀÂÊÔÃÕÜÇ ]", RegexOptions.Compiled)) throw new ArgumentException("Nome inválido: \"" + nome + "\".");

    return nome;
}
```

---

## Na prática

Executei o código acima em uma base com dezenas de milhares de nomes brasileiros (por volta de 100,000).

Destes obtive os seguintes falsos positivos:

- `ñ`: *PEÑA*, *CAMIÑA*, *YÁÑEZ*, *MUÑOZ* e *MUÑIZ*.
- `'`: *SAINT'CLAIR*.
- `-`: *SAINT-CLAIR*.

Além do nome do nosso colega @jpkrohling:

- `ö`: KRÖHLING.

Outra curiosidade é que alguns poucos registros estão com o espaço em branco [NBSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (160), ao invés do espaço em branco *comum* SP (32). A validação também detectou isso (e, em nosso caso, resolvemos substituir).

---

## Tratando nomes internacionais

Tratar nomes, especialmente em âmbito internacional, não é uma tarefa simples. O tratamento acima falharia como nomes relativamente comuns como [Björk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bj%C3%B6rk_%28name%29), [Marić](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mari%C4%87); ou não tão comuns como [Graham-Cumming](http://blog.jgc.org/2010/06/your-last-name-contains-invalid.html).

Além disso, quando sendo mais permissivo, [cuidado com uma eventual brecha a um ataque XSS](http://xkcd.com/327/). Um exemplo seria o uso do [apóstrofo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%B3strofo). [Alguns nomes utilizam o apóstrofo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Use_in_non-English_names), que muitas vezes é representado (erroneamente?) pelo caractere de aspas simples (`'`) ao invés do caractere correto (`’`).

Fica o aviso.

Comment: +1 pelo xkcd, embora eu veja pouca aplicação prática nesse tipo de validação, já que até cidades podem ter nomes com caracteres diferentes como [`'` (apóstrofo)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pau-d'Arco_(Tocantins)) e [`- `(traço)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A3o-Me-Toque).

Comment: @utluiz, sim mas a idéia é validar **nome de pessoas**. Acabei (realmente) precisando implementar essa validação em um sistema ontem, achei interessante documentar aqui o que acabei pesquisando/implementando :)

Comment: Outro exemplo internacional que falha é Muñoz e afins. Fiquei curioso, por que validar somente nomes brasileiros e vetar internacionais? Uma sanitização contra XSS e SQL injection não bastaria?

Comment: @talles Você poderia satisfazer nossa curiosidade e revelar o motivo da exigência desse tipo de validação para o sistema? =)

Comment: Vale notar que alguns caracteres são inválidos para as regras de gramática, mas são perfeitamente válidos para nomes. Por exemplo, ö (o com trema), que aparece em meus documentos oficiais (RG, CPF, passaporte).

Comment: Nesse sistema em específico, é importante que o nome real usuários cadastrados estejam bem formados. Por haveram muitos usuários e integração com outros sistemas foi tomada a decisão de ser rigoroso nesse cadastro. Decidimos tratar eventuais exceções conforme forem ocorrendo (posso até atualizar a resposta quando isso ocorrer).

Comment: Mas alguns motivos poderiam ser uma falha de encoding por parte de outro sistema integrante ou algum usuário brincando com caracteres Unicode por exemplo.

Comment: @jpkrohling, interessante, seu nome já falharia a validação. Eu cheguei a ler sobre um caso (emissão de passaporte) em que a letra *não convencional* foi substituida pela mais similar (*ö* para *o* no seu caso), mas pelo visto isso não ocorreu com você. Por preucação vou ver se consigo executar a validação nos nomes existentes em nossa base (que são alguns belos milhares).

Comment: @jpkrohling, se importaria de dizer qual seu nome ou sobrenome que possui a trema (só ele, não precisa ser seu nome completo). Apenas para adicionar à resposta.

Comment: É a última parte do meu login aqui, trocando o "o" por "ö", então, não tem problema: Kröhling :-)

Answer (score 22):

No Brasil não existem restrições sobre os nomes das pessoas. A lei só menciona que não pode expor a pessoa a ridículo, fora isto, é permitido. E mesmo assim nada impede que um estrangeiro esteja morando no país e precise ser cadastrado no seu sistema.

Desta forma não adianta apenas prever uma regra de validação que considere as letras do alfabeto latino (de A-Z) e seus acentos. Também é necessário prever exceções para apóstrofos, hífens, sequência de números romanos (William Gates III, por exemplo), caracteres gregos... A lista de exceções seria gigantesca e provavelmente deixaria alguma coisa de fora, gerando erro para algum usuário específico.

Existe também o problema de encodings, e dependendo do tratamento que os sistemas relacionados dêem aos caracteres, um nome poderia ser impresso em outro sistema de uma forma totalmente incompreensível.

Em geral, se você impede que um usuário se cadastre no seu sistema porque o nome dele não é aceito, você está perdendo um potencial cliente. Apenas valide se o campo foi preenchido e não corra riscos.

Comment: Pois é, em geral tem que tomar cuidado ao ser restritivo. Mas em alguns cenários (excepcionais) a assertividade é mais importante que a quantidade (como foi no meu). p.s.: algarismos romanos não deixam de ser letras!

Comment: @talles talvez ele se refira ao fato da _sequencia de números romanos_ ou de forma mais precisa a sequencia de alguns caracteres iguais o que pode ser considerado errôneo, embora de certa forma isso vá contra a ideia (que eu concordo) de ser menos restritivo.

Comment: Nesse mesmo caso, permitir ou não nomes estrangeiros com caracteres não latinos?